# Oracle Pattern matching in group by clause

Tags: oracle

H,

How to use Pattern Matching function in "group By" clause.

Below is the Data

```
emp_name transaction_id 
John      1001
John=     1002
Peter     1003
```

I want to group by based on emp_name. Here 'John' and 'John=' both are same employee. I want to ignore if the employee name has '=' sign at the end of the column.

Expected Result:

```
Emp_name  countt
John      2
Peter     1
```

Comment: is the '='only limitation?

Comment: Yes. '=' is the only condition

Comment: It needs to ignore if the '=' sign is at end. For Eg, John and Jo=hn is different. but John and John= is same employee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` works fine and is fast. But since you asked for pattern matching, here is an answer with a pattern:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(emp_name, '=$', ''), count(*) AS countt
  FROM employees
 GROUP BY regexp_replace(emp_name, '=$', '');
```

Comment: You were the first to handle that the = should only be replaced at the end of the name...

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  replace (emp_name, '=', '') as emp_name,
  count (*) as countt
from employees
group by replace (emp_name, '=', '')
```

Edit, since you said the name can contain an =

```
select
  case
    when emp_name like '%='
      then substr (emp_name, 1, length (emp_name) - 1)
    else emp_name
  end as emp_name,
  count (1) as countt
from employees
group by
  case
    when emp_name like '%='
      then substr (emp_name, 1, length (emp_name) - 1)
    else emp_name
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple case statement replacing only the right most = if one exists.

```
SELECT case when right(emp_name,1) = '=' then left(emp_Name,len(emp_name-1))
       else emp_name end as EmpName, count(Transaction_ID) countt
FROM dataTable
GROUP BY case when right(emp_name,1) = '=' then left(emp_Name,len(emp_name-1))
        else emp_name end
```

Comment: It needs to ignore if the '=' sign is at end. For Eg, John and Jo=hn is different. but John and John= is same employee.